# Section Single Title Caching

Tags: cache, sections

I have the following -

```
{% set press = craft.entries.section('press').first() %}

{{ press.title }}
```

If I change the section title in the Sections area of the back end from something like "Press" to "Testimonials" - I still see Press when I call press.title. The section is set to a single.

I've tried clearing cache in the back end which doesn't seem to do the trick. Any advice?

Comment: Mind adding that as an official answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone stuck on this -- when changing a Section's name you have to goto the entry under Entries and hit save. This will update the mysql row / title.

Comment: This makes sense now that I know it, but it's incredibly unintuitive